# How do I handle or manage commands which are sent by server in unity?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

In my game there are 10 objects which are just started running on play as this is a web player game and betting as well and it requires some socket programming.

At run time the commands are sent by server and client machine accepts these commands as well but I don't have any idea that how can I manage these commands and how do I executes that commands as per the requirements?

If anyone knows please try to help me out..!
Thanks

Comment: What part exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually commands are getting stored but I don't know how to perform that and my game is pixelating and not running smooth, its jerky I guess.